# Slowly decaying vehicles

Tags: riddle, word

> It cannot quite talk back
>   (Well, almost cannot),
>   Nor used to measure value.
>   It's sticky but not brown.
>
> Clad in warning colours,
>   But ever so good to eat.
>   Often found in winter
>   To make a colder nose.

What does this short riddle describe?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Is it...

> A carrot?
>  (the "car-rot" the title is referring to, thanks @gnovice)

It cannot quite talk back

> Not quite a parrot

(Well, almost cannot)

> Carrot is written almost like "cannot"

Nor used to measure value.

> Not quite a carat

It's sticky but not brown.

> Looks like a stick, but orange (thanks @Chris and @gnovice)

Clad in warning colours,

> Carrots are orange

But ever so good to eat.

> I do agree

Often found in winter
To make a colder nose.

> Often used for a snowman's nose

Comment: That's a very sticky parrot you got there!

Comment: With reference to the missed clues, think diamonds and (blank) sticks.

Comment: Also, break the word up and you get the title.

Comment: Thanks @gnovice, finally got this one. But still miss the "sticky" hint. Language barrier probably.

Comment: It's Sticky, as in "Stick like"  but not brown.

Comment: slowly decaying vehicles?

Comment: @Jordan.J.D Answer updated. Thanks all for your help

Comment: I suspect the first two lines don't refer to the same thing. There's a more obvious meaning to _well, almost cannot_.

Comment: You got it! Just the 2nd line left to explain.

Comment: @Randal'Thor OK, I just gave it a try

Comment: Yup, that's it. Your green checkmark is in the post and will arrive in 6-8 weeks :-)

Comment: @Rand al'Thor: Missed opportunity to reference caret (The ^ character)

Comment: Oh, you did too!

Answer (score 2):

Is it...

> Honey?

It cannot quite talk back

> Honey cannot talk back

Well, almost cannot

> The bee that it is made from might be able to talk back.

Nor used to measure value.

> Honey is not used to measure value.

It's sticky but not brown.

> Honey is not brown but it is sticky.

Clad in warning colours.

> Yellow is often seen as a color of warning, a reason why construction hats are yellow.

But ever so good to eat.

> To some people, Honey is delicious.

Often found in winter

> Honey is found in many households in the winter.

To make a colder nose

> Honey is often used as a treatment when you are sick with a cold.

Comment: "Honey color ranges from nearly colorless to dark brown" - https://www.honey.com/newsroom/presskit/honey-color-and-flavor

Comment: @Jordan.J.D Honey is often mostly attributed with the color yellow.